# EOSIO: name.value secondary index returns end iterator, even though searched value exists in table

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, c++

I've got a multi-index table going with two secondary indices:

```
TABLE entry {
   uint64_t                id = 0;
   eosio::name             player;
   std::vector<uint16_t>   allocation;
   uint64_t                starttime;
   uint64_t                betroundid;
   double                  talliedpoints;
   bool                    funded;

   uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
   uint64_t by_secondary() const { return betroundid; }
   uint64_t by_tertiary() const { return player.value; }

   EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( entry, (id)(player)(allocation)(starttime)(betroundid)(talliedpoints)(funded) )
};


typedef eosio::multi_index<eosio::name("entry"), entry,
  eosio::indexed_by<eosio::name("betroundid"),
    eosio::const_mem_fun<entry, uint64_t, &entry::by_secondary>
  >,
  eosio::indexed_by<eosio::name("playerval"),
    eosio::const_mem_fun<entry, uint64_t, &entry::by_tertiary>
  >
> entry_index;


entry_index entries;
```

Creating, modifying, and getting entries as usual with `entries.find(id)` works fine. But when I try to pull the `playerval` index and find an `eosio::name.value` in it, I get an iterator in end state:

```
auto get_unfunded_entry_by_player( const name player_to_get, 
                                   const asset &funding )
{
   auto entries_idx = entries.get_index<name("playerval")>();
   auto entry_itr = entries_idx.find( player_to_get.value );

   eosio_assert( entry_itr != entries_idx.end(), "No entries found for this player!" );

   while ( entry_itr->funded == true || 
           entry_itr->totalbet != funding.amount )
   {
      eosio_assert( ++entry_itr != entries_idx.end(), "No matching unfunded entries found!" );
   }
   return get_entry( entry_itr->id );
}
```

"No entries found for this player!" is always thrown, even though by using `eosio::print` and `cleos get table`, I've verified that the `player_to_get` is the same name as the `player` in the table.

Does anything seem to be amiss? Appreciate any help in advance, been fighting with this for hours now:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was the scope of the table in the contract constructor. The changes required to get the constructor up to speed with October's CDT updates hadn't been correctly completed, and so some things worked and others didn't. Once that was fixed, everything worked:

```
acontractname( name receiver, name code, datastream <const char *> ds ):
            contract( receiver, code, ds ),
            entries ( receiver, receiver.value )
            {}
```